# Return closest span from caret position in contenteditable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, contenteditable

If caret placed on word **gallery** ( or on other word between those two span tags ) how can I get data-id from span element with jQuery?

```
<div class="editor" contenteditable="true">
<p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and
typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text
ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a <span data-id="1"></span>galley
of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.</p>
<p> It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic
typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.<span data-id-end="1"></span> It was
popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum
passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including
versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get attribute data-id using this code in jQuery

```js
console.log($("span").attr("data-id"));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span data-id="3"></span>
```

Comment: That's not the issue. Question is how can I get span data-id if caret is placed between those to span tags, but not inside span tag.

Answer (score 0):

You can get idea from it

```js
var texta=$("span").nextUntil("span").text().trim();
var starting_sign = texta.indexOf("+");
var ending_sign = texta.indexOf(".");
console.log(texta.substring(starting_sign, ending_sign));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span></span>
This is text + pick it . for example
<span></span>
```